# Import Response Data received from an API into CSV file

Tags: java, api, csv, jackson, rest-assured

I'm trying to store a data taken from the API response into CSV file using `Rest Assured`.
That's how my code looks like:

```
public void Test_01() throws Exception {
    Response response = RestAssured.given() // enter valid credentials
            .get("https://gorest.co.in/public-api/users")
            .then()
            .extract()
            .response();

    String data = response.jsonPath().get("data");

    System.out.println(response.asString().getClass());
    try
    {
        JsonNode jsonTree = new ObjectMapper().readTree(data);
        CsvSchema.Builder csvSchemaBuilder = CsvSchema.builder();
        JsonNode firstObject = jsonTree.elements().next();
        firstObject.fieldNames().forEachRemaining(fieldName -> {csvSchemaBuilder.addColumn(fieldName);} );
        CsvSchema csvSchema = csvSchemaBuilder.build().withHeader();
        CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
        csvMapper.writerFor(JsonNode.class)
                .with(csvSchema)
                .writeValue(new File("src/main/resources/lmsget.csv"), jsonTree);

    }   catch(Exception ex)

    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

When I try to execute this test, I am getting an error: `Schema specified that header line is to be written; but contains no column names`. Maybe, that's because of the format of the JSON, which looks like:

```
"code": 200,
"meta": {
"pagination": {
"total": 2610,
"pages": 131,
"page": 1,
"limit": 20
}
```

After that, comes an array `data` with objects in it. I just want to store that data only.
I've also tried some changes in extracting response as `JsonPath`:

```
Object data = response.JsonPath.get("data");
```

But when I use it in `JsonNode jsonTree = new ObjectMapper().readTree(data);` I am getting error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('i' (code 105)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
at [Source: (String)"[{id=2583, name=Aryan Shah, email=shah_aryan@oreilly.biz, gender=male, status=inactive},
```

Comment: It's better if you provide full json response, structure of your expected csv, change the title of question and add tag `jackson`. Rest-Assured CANNOT convert from json to csv, you're using classes of Jackson to achieve that.

Comment: https://gorest.co.in/public-api/users - this is full json response.

Comment: it works fine for this API: https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/posts, because it does not have additional fields, like code, meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

- Step 1: Convert response to json in String format
- Step 2: Extract array `data` by Jackson, not Rest-Assured

```
String res = given()
                .get("https://gorest.co.in/public-api/users")
                .asString();
try {
     JsonNode jsonTree = new ObjectMapper().readTree(res).get("data");
     ...
}
```